# ERROR in node_modules/angular2-hotkeys/lib/hotkey.model.d.ts(24,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I am using angular 7 with

> "angular2-hotkeys": "^2.1.4",
>   ..

At the running angular project, I got that error:

ERROR in node_modules/angular2-hotkeys/lib/hotkey.model.d.ts(24,9): error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I got the answer, install the following package with the correct version

```
npm install angular2-hotkeys@2.1.4
```

instead of install

```
npm install angular2-hotkeys
```

You should install the exact version mention in the package.json. Sometimes latest version will not be working smoothly with other packages and versions

Answer (score 0):

try doing

> ng update @angular/core @angular/cli
>
> npm install angular2-hotkeys@latest